# How to install Android Studio with Appcelerator Titanium together in Windows?

Tags: java, android-studio, installation, appcelerator

apparently these two can not exist together because Appcelerator uses 32bit Java and Android Studio uses 64bit Java, Will there be any way to make them capable to live?

Answer (score 0):

One way (probably not the best) is to the the JAVA_HOME environment variable to the path to the 32 bit jdk bin folder. The same for the 64 bit version when using android studio. This obviously requires both versions to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

Appcelerator has close to releasing a significant change to Titanium Studio and their development environment.  Perhaps when that change becomes public, which should be in a few weeks, then the 32 java may no longer be a requirement.